# debug what is being copied by processResources task in Gradle

Tags: gradle, grails

I've been looking at the task `processResources`, a [Copy type](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task, defined on the [java gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/java_plugin.html), to understand what artefacts are being copied during my build process. I'm getting into trouble trying to figure out what other plugins in the Gradle project have (probably) changed in the `sourceSets` source (`from`) and destination (`into`) directories for this task. The plugin's docs aren't clear at what has been changed and I can't even know which plugin is changing what.

To figure out exactly what is being copied, from where and where to, I wonder if there is:

1. a verbose debug mode for the `Copy` task, which lists each file being copied, including origin and destination;

or (better)

2. how to show contents of the processResources task properties: `source`, `includes`, `excludes` and `destinationDir` as they have been (re)defined by any of the installed plugins in my gradle project.

I've already tried `gradle processResources -debug` but it is not displaying any useful information.

Any Gradle command line or script snippet will be appreciated. BTW, I'm using [spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) and [grails gradle](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin) plugins.

Comment: so far I came to this snippet that shows the destination (into) dirs, but not the source (from) ones:  `Copy pr = tasks.getByName("processResources") as Copy; println "destinationDir: "+pr.destinationDir;`

Comment: Did you solve this question? The task is a mystery to me. It somehow executes other copy tasks somewhere in my Gradle scripts. I would like to know what and why and how to omit this behaviour.

Comment: If anyone has more info about this processResources task I'd be also very thankful to hear about it. In our build pipeline processResources is taking about 15 minutes (yes!). It's a real nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve all my issues with below configs. Hope it helps

> customSourceSet.java will sets the source and destination of java
> files customSourceSet.resources sets the source of resources
> customSourceSet.output sets the destination of resources

```
sourceSets {
  customSourceSet {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/customSourceSet/javafiles']
      destinationDirectory = file("../../DISTER/acceptance/classes")
    }
    resources {
      srcDirs("src/customSourceSet/resources") // or use [] if more resources
    }
    output.resourcesDir = file('../../DISTER/acceptance/classes')
  }
}
processTestResources{
  doFirst
  {
            println ('Copying Resources : '+source.asPath)
            println ('Copying To : '+destinationDir)
  }
}
```